# The C compiler is not able to compile a simple test program

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I'm trying to build one project from the GitHub, namely this project https://github.com/notAlaanor/cpp-type-highlighter (it's just repo of another guy).

But after trying to compile it I get an erros like:

```
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.20.27404.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.20.27404.0
-- Check for working C compiler: E:/VS19/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.20.27404/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: E:/VS19/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.20.27404/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):

The C compiler

        "E:/VS19/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.20.27404/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe"

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/theha/cpp-type-highlighter/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"nmake" "/nologo" "cmTC_b368f\fast"
        E:\VS19\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27404\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_b368f.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_b368f.dir\build
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_b368f.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
        E:\VS19\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27404\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe @C:\Users\theha\AppData\Local\Temp\nm8555.tmp
    testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_b368f.exe
        "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_b368f.dir --manifests  -- E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_b368f.dir\objects1.rsp @C:\Users\theha\AppData\Local\Temp\nm85C3.tmp
    LINK Pass 1: command "E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_b368f.dir\objects1.rsp /out:cmTC_b368f.exe /implib:cmTC_b368f.lib /pdb:C:\Users\theha\cpp-type-highlighter\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_b368f.pdb /version:0.0 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\cmTC_b368f.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\cmTC_b368f.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1) with the following output:
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find /nologo: No such file or directory
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find /out:cmTC_b368f.exe: No such file or directory
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find /implib:cmTC_b368f.lib: No such file or directory
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find /pdb:C:\Users\theha\cpp-type-highlighter\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_b368f.pdb: Invalid argument
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find /version:0.0: No such file or directory
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find /debug: No such file or directory
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find /INCREMENTAL: No such file or directory
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find /subsystem:console: No such file or directory
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find kernel32.lib: No such file or directory
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find user32.lib: No such file or directory
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find gdi32.lib: No such file or directory
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find winspool.lib: No such file or directory
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find shell32.lib: No such file or directory
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find ole32.lib: No such file or directory
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find oleaut32.lib: No such file or directory
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find uuid.lib: No such file or directory
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find comdlg32.lib: No such file or directory
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find advapi32.lib: No such file or directory
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find /MANIFEST: No such file or directory
    E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: cannot find /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\cmTC_b368f.dir/intermediate.manifest: Invalid argument
    CMakeFiles\cmTC_b368f.dir/manifest.res: file not recognized: file format not recognized
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"' : return code '0xffffffff'
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'E:\VS19\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27404\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

If I run command `where clang` I get an output:

```
C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe
```

Also I run command `cmake ..` through `vcvarsall.bat`, so, before I run `cmake ..`, I run `call "E:\VS19\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" amd64`.
I building on Windows 10, I had Visual Studio 2019 and MinGW.

How to fix that issue?

Comment: And your test program actually is?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Hi, I just try to build project from GitHub of another guy.

Comment: You're mixing build tools - using Microsoft's compiler (cl.exe) with MinGW's linker, but passing Microsoft link options.

Comment: "I had Visual Studio 2019 and MinGW." - And, according to the log, **Visual Studio** compiler (`cl`) is used along with **MinGW** linker (`E:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe`). They would never work together. Ensure, that you use `Visual Studio 16 2019` [CMake generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake-generators.7.html).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Hi, yeah, I think so, but how to fix this? It's not my project I just try to build it of another guy?

Comment: @Tsyvarev mb I can pass any command "keys" to cmake to tell him that I want to build through ms cl?

Comment: Yes, that "key" is known as `-G` option for command line `cmake`, and "Generator" field in the CMake GUI.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok, I run command `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" ..` and get error `CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio 16 2019`
If I change it to  `Visual Studio 15 2017` I get error
`  Generator

    Visual Studio 15 2017

  could not find any instance of Visual Studio.`

Comment: It seems that your CMake version is not high enough for understand generator "Visual Studio 16 2019". If you want to choose another generator, then follow the advice in the error message and remove `CMakeCache.txt` and `CMakeFiles` directory.

Comment: @Tsyvarev already do that. But stil have error `Generator Visual Studio 15 2017 could not find any instance of Visual Studio.`

Comment: It looks normal that CMake cannot find "Visual Studio 15 2017" as you don't have it, doesn't it?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I had this `MSVC v141 – VS 2017 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.16)` already installed, it's not enough?

Comment: Have you activate `vcvarsall.bat` for using it?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yeah, first I run `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "E:\VS19\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"` from Win + R, and then `call "E:\VS19\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" amd64`

Comment: Aren't you need to activate `vcvarsall.bat` which corresponds to Visual Studio which you want to use? That is, activating `vcvarsall.bat` from VS19 doesn't help in using VS17.

Comment: @Tsyvarev oh.. So, I installed VS 19, but I also installed `MSVC v141 – VS 2017 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.16)` through **Visual Studio Installer** and I had only one `vcvarsall.bat` I think ((

Comment: Actually, I am not an expert in using Visual Studio with CMake. May be, someone else will help you.

Comment: Doesn't Visual Studio 2019 understand CMakeFiles ? You might not actually need to run CMake yourself.

Comment: @MSalters Can be more?

Answer (score -1):

You may have to retarget and rebuild the solution if you've downloaded it.

Right click solution -> Retarget solution -> Select relvent/latest SDK.

Right click solution -> Rebuild Solution.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, I needed to do that in Visual Studio? So, I need to open this in VS as project? It's not my project I just try to build this.

Comment: Nope - the symptoms would differ.